# Source map plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, eclipse-plugin, productivity-power-tools

I was wondering if there is a source map plugin available for Eclipse like the one included in VS' Productivity Power Tools:
[image]

Tried to Google it but I've not got any relevant hit.

Comment: You will need to be more specific.  What is the source map plugin?  If it is the code outline on the right, then I have never seen anything like this...

Comment: Yes, I meant the zoomed out column on the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it https://github.com/apauzies/eclipse-minimap-view something you are looking for?

Comment: Yes this is it. I mark this as answer because this plugin is not that robust than PDE-Tools.

Answer (score 3):

How about this group of plugins:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pde-tools#.UXcQ4ILZpP0

It includes a "Crazy outline view".  I have not used the plugin, so I can't vouch for its quality, but I do know the plugin author and he has a record of releasing good plugins.  It's worth a shot.